# Is it possible to implicitly reference a member of the parent object from within a function of a child object?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way, without explicitly calling the parent object by its instance name, to refer to the parent object's members?  In the below example, the statement `this.me` refers to the `me` member of `child`.  I know I can do something like `var who = obj.me`, but I was curious if there was a more implicit method of going about this?

```
var obj = {
    me: 'obj',
    child: {
        me: 'child',
        init: function() {
            var p = document.getElementById('console');
            var who = this.me;
            p.innerHTML = who;
        }
    }
};

obj.child.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3CQ8f/4/

Comment: No because otherwise with `var child = { };var parent1 = { child: child };var parent2 = { child: child };` what would "parent" on child return?
Objets referencing each other form a graph, not a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this, but you could just create a reference to the parent in your object definition:

```
var obj = {
    me: 'obj'
};

obj.child = {
    me: 'child',
    parent: obj,
    init: function() {
        var p = document.getElementById('console');
        var who = this.parent.me;
        p.innerHTML = who;
    }
};
```